# Flight to Canada 20-hour layover in Narita. Filipino

Tags: transit, filipino-citizens, nrt

I have one itinerary booking from Manila to Canada, but I need to change planes in Japan (Narita airport) from Cebu Pacific to ZipAir. I have an overnight layover at Narita Airport.

Do you know if Cebu Pacific issues or assists you in Narita for the shore pass. It's just for a 20-hour layover. I have my visa to Canada & all documentations needed. So I just want to confirm if there’s assistance from them.

Comment: Are the two flights on the same ticket?

Comment: @jcaron It's pretty much guaranteed they're not, since both Cebu and Zip are LCCs.

Comment: One or two ticket(s) isn't so much the problem, as much as 'Do these airlines interline?', which, as lambshaanxy points out, being LCCs, don't.

Comment: @jcaron - Yes, they are booked in one itinerary from Trip.com. I have a friend from Japan whom I asked to check it for me and indeed they will issue a shore pass if you have a ticket/boarding pass to your next destination. This will allow you to go out of Japan up to 72hrs. I just need to approach the airport personel or ask the immigration for the pass. This applies to all, including PH passort holder.

Answer (score 9):

I have bad news for you: **you will need a Japanese visa for this connection, and you will be denied boarding if you don't have one**.

I'm not sure how you managed to book Cebu and ZipAir on the same itinerary, but both are point-to-point low cost carriers that do not offer connections with other airlines.  You will thus need to clear immigration, collect and recheck your bags, and pass through immigration again, and for Philippines citizens [this requires a visa](https://www.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/transit_visa.html#:%7E:text=For%20travelers%20who%20are%20stopping,country%20need%20a%20transit%20visa.).

What's more, Narita is not a 24-hour airport, it closes at night and all transit passengers are herded outside.  So if you have an overnight layover, you need a visa, full stop.

Shore passes are available at the discretion of immigration officials for passengers who have a legal airside transit through Japanese airports, and can complete their journey even if the shore pass is refused.  Unfortunately you do not qualify.

Comment: "On the same itinerary" Probably not in the usual, one-PNR, meaning. More like, possibly, look I bought 2 tickets, that's my itinerary...